# How to subscribe to stack exchange blog?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I didn't find any subscribe button on the [blog page](http://blog.stackexchange.com/). How do I subscribe to the blog anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, the RSS feed links *are* on the blog page. They're on the right-hand side, below the Archive links, and above the Flair buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Link to the feed.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/)

Most browsers put an RSS icon up in the address bar (all the way on the right) if an RSS feed is available.  Clicking on that will take you to the feed.